# JobSheduler крашит приложение, если в момент его срабатывания приложение выгружено из памяти

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service, android-asynctask, livedata

Итак, стоит простая задача: периодически синхронизировать локальную БД с удаленным API. Делается это при помощи JobSheduler с setPeriodic.

Проблема в том, что все отлично работает когда приложение находится в памяти (активно или свернуто - не играет роли). Когда оно выгружено и запускается самим JobSheduler - получаю краш.

И так, схема работы такова: либо в ходе обработки нажатия кнопки с UI, либо при получении BOOT_COMPLETE, вызывается статический метод makeSyncNowAndScheduleNewsSyncJob (в качестве параметра контекста туда прилетает либо контекст из onReceive или getApplication из Activity, через ViewModel) который инициирует JobSheduler, работа которого выполнять синхронизацию БД, которая будет запускаться каждые 15 минут (в случае если вызвать его несколько раз, будет проведена синхронизация и ее повторение через 15 минут - тут все корректно, проверено).

```
import android.app.job.JobInfo
import android.app.job.JobParameters
import android.app.job.JobScheduler
import android.app.job.JobService
import android.content.ComponentName
import android.content.Context

class SynchronizeNewsJobService : JobService() {

    companion object {
        fun makeSyncNowAndScheduleNewsSyncJob(context: Context) {
            val synchronizeNewsJobServiceComponent = ComponentName(context, SynchronizeNewsJobService::class.java)
            val builder = JobInfo.Builder(0, synchronizeNewsJobServiceComponent)
            builder.setPeriodic(1000 * 60 * 15)
            val jobScheduler = context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE) as JobScheduler
            jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build())
        }
    }

    override fun onStartJob(params: JobParameters?): Boolean {
        (application as NewsApplication).articleRepository.syncArticlesWithApi()
        return false
    }

    override fun onStopJob(params: JobParameters?): Boolean {
        return false
    }
}
```

В onStartJob мы получаем инстанс апликейшена, который в себе содержит репозиторий.

```
import android.app.Application

    class NewsApplication : Application() {
         val articleRepository by lazy { ArticleRepository(this) }
    }
```

Был опробован вариант с инициализацией поля в методе onCreate, проблему это не решило.

На репозитории вызывается метод syncArticlesWithApi(), который в свою очередь получает из запущенного асинктаска список обьектов с удалеенного АПИ, сравнивает их с теми что уже есть в наличии в БД, и в случае если там есть обьекты которых в бд еще нет, добавляет их туда (попутно выдавая нотификацию о этом, и обновляя в перфернсах дату последнего обновления. 
Тут тоже все работоспособно, т.к как указанно выше этот код работает без нареканий когда приложение активно.

```
import android.app.Notification
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.AsyncTask
import android.preference.PreferenceManager
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.Request
import org.json.JSONObject
import java.util.*

class ArticleRepository(applicationContext: Context) {

    companion object {
        private const val NEWS_API_KEY = "*****"
        private const val NEWS_API_URL = "http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=ua&apiKey=$NEWS_API_KEY"
        private const val ARTICLES_MAX_COUNT = 50
        const val PREF_LAST_UPDATE_TIME = "LAST_UPDATED"
    }

    private val mAppContext = applicationContext
    private val mArticleDao: ArticleDao = NewsRoomDatabase.getDatabase(mAppContext).articleDao()
    val allArticlesLiveDataList: LiveData<List<Article>> = mArticleDao.getAllArticlesLiveData()


    fun syncArticlesWithApi() {
        val freshArticlesList =
            GetArticlesListFromUrlAsyncTask().execute(ArticleRepository.NEWS_API_URL).get().toMutableList()
        freshArticlesList.removeAll(allArticlesLiveDataList.value!!)

        if (!freshArticlesList.isEmpty()) {
            insertArticles(freshArticlesList)
            showNotification(mAppContext, "News synced", freshArticlesList.size.toString() + " new articles added")

            val sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mAppContext)
            sharedPref.edit()
                .putLong(PREF_LAST_UPDATE_TIME, System.currentTimeMillis())
                .apply()
        }
    }

    private fun insertArticles(articlesList: List<Article>) {
        InsertAsyncTask(mArticleDao).execute(articlesList)
        deleteEldestArticles(ArticleRepository.ARTICLES_MAX_COUNT)
    }

    private fun deleteEldestArticles(limitOfArticleTableRows: Int) {
        DeleteEldestArticlesAsyncTask(mArticleDao).execute(limitOfArticleTableRows)
    }

    private fun showNotification(context: Context, title: CharSequence, message: CharSequence) {
        val managerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)

        val intent = Intent(context, NewsFeedActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 333, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

        val notificaitonBuilder: Notification.Builder

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            notificaitonBuilder = Notification.Builder(context, "333")
        } else
            notificaitonBuilder = Notification.Builder(context)
        notificaitonBuilder
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
            .build()

        managerCompat.notify(333, notificaitonBuilder.build())
    }

    private class InsertAsyncTask(articleDao: ArticleDao) : AsyncTask<List<Article>, Unit, Unit>() {
        private val mArticleDao = articleDao

        override fun doInBackground(vararg articles: List<Article>) {
            mArticleDao.insertAll(articles[0])
        }
    }

    private class GetArticlesListFromUrlAsyncTask : AsyncTask<String, Unit, List<Article>>() {

        private fun readJsonFromUrl(url: String): JSONObject {
            val client = OkHttpClient()
            val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
            val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
            return JSONObject(response.body()?.string())
        }

        override fun doInBackground(vararg url: String): List<Article> {
            val json = readJsonFromUrl(url[0])
            val articlesArrayJson = json.getJSONArray("articles")
            val articleList = LinkedList<Article>()

            for (i in 0 until articlesArrayJson.length()) {
                val articleJson = articlesArrayJson.getJSONObject(i)
                val article = Article(
                    null,
                    articleJson.getJSONObject("source").getString("name"),
                    articleJson.getString("author"),
                    articleJson.getString("title"),
                    articleJson.getString("url"),
                    articleJson.getString("urlToImage"),
                    articleJson.getString("publishedAt")
                )
                articleList.add(article)
            }
            return articleList
        }
    }

    private class DeleteEldestArticlesAsyncTask(articleDao: ArticleDao) : AsyncTask<Int, Unit, Unit>() {
        private val mArticleDao = articleDao
        override fun doInBackground(vararg limitOfArticleTableRows: Int?) {
            mArticleDao.deleteEldestArticles(limitOfArticleTableRows[0]!!)
        }
    }
}
```

Ну и на всякий случай слой непосредственной работы с БД - ДАО:

```
import android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData
import android.arch.persistence.room.Dao
import android.arch.persistence.room.Insert
import android.arch.persistence.room.OnConflictStrategy
import android.arch.persistence.room.Query

@Dao
interface ArticleDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertAll(articleList: List<Article>)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM article_table ORDER BY publish_date DESC")
    fun getAllArticlesLiveData(): LiveData<List<Article>>

    @Query(
        "DELETE FROM article_table WHERE publish_date = (SELECT MIN (publish_date) FROM article_table)"
                + " AND (SELECT count(*) FROM article_table) = :limitOfArticleTableRows"
    )
    fun deleteEldestArticles(limitOfArticleTableRows: Int)
}
```

И сама сущность, с которой мы работаем:

```
import android.arch.persistence.room.ColumnInfo
import android.arch.persistence.room.Entity
import android.arch.persistence.room.Index
import android.arch.persistence.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity(
    tableName = "article_table", indices = [Index(
        value = ["title"],
        unique = true
    )]
)
data class Article(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id: Int?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "source_name") var sourceName: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "author_name") var authorName: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "title") var title: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "url") var url: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "image_url") var imageUrl: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "publish_date") var publishDate: String

) {
    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false

        other as Article

        if (sourceName != other.sourceName) return false
        if (authorName != other.authorName) return false
        if (title != other.title) return false
        if (url != other.url) return false
        if (imageUrl != other.imageUrl) return false
        if (publishDate != other.publishDate) return false

        return true
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        var result = sourceName.hashCode()
        result = 31 * result + authorName.hashCode()
        result = 31 * result + title.hashCode()
        result = 31 * result + url.hashCode()
        result = 31 * result + imageUrl.hashCode()
        result = 31 * result + publishDate.hashCode()
        return result
    }
}
```

В манифестве класс апликейшена, сервиса, бут_комплит_ресивера зареганы, пермишены на BIND_JOB_SERVICE тоже на месте.

Исходя из главного условия воспроизведения бага - на момент срабатывания джобскедулера приложение не запущенно, есть подозрение что дело в контексте, однако я везде пользуюсь апликейшн контекстом, который по идее не должен быть null.
Собственно вопрос: в чем заключается моя ошибка и причина бага

Comment: Вы не написали самого главного - что за ошибка и на какой строке и какой у неё лог)

Comment: Если бы я мог это увидеть  - справился бы сам. Но как я могу логировать приложение которое до момента краша вообще не запущенно)?

Comment: Ну... В логах то должно же что-то быть... Вроде я не встречал за много лет ситуаций, когда в логи вообще ничего при краше не выводится... Может быть стоит попробовать какое-то приложение поставить которое логи системы читает и через него посмотреть, если вы в студии логи не видите. Ну или проверить, что в студии в логах фильтров никаких не стоит

Comment: А как я в студии посмотрю логи? Для того чтоб воспроизвести баг - приложение нужно закрыть (в студии я получаю Application terminated - и все, никаких логов стектрейсов и т.д я не получаю). Есть только идея попробовать логировать в самом приложении таким образом, чтоб логи оставались на устройстве, через преференсы или что-то в этом роде.

Comment: По идее вы должны получать логи когда приложение перезапустится. Возможно логов у вас нет, т.к. вы поставили фильтр на только выбранное прилоджение. Попробуйте убрать фильтр, если он есть. Если его нет и логов всё равно нет... Тогда, наверное, действительно только ручное логгирование в файл поможет. Хотя наверняка дело в фильтре или можно сторонним приложением логи посмотреть.

Comment: Записал стактрейс в преференсы, выяснилось: Выпадает в  ArticleRepository, в методе syncArticlesWithApi()
на строке
freshArticlesList.removeAll(allArticlesLiveDataList.value!!)

Comment: Вы не раскрываете типа ошибки, сделаю предположение, что у вас `NPE` - `allArticlesLiveDataList.value` - `null`. Контекст на месте, иначе ещё на этапе инициализации свалилось бы. БД также нормально инициализируется. Т.е. надо выяснить поему у вас в `LiveData` `null`. Тут уж ничем помочь не могу - не разу с ней дела не имел) Возможно стоит почитать доку по её интеграции с `Room`. Возможно дело в том, что данные не успевают загрузиться на момент обращения к ним. Попробуйте убрать обёртку `LiveData` над методом `getAllArticlesLiveData` и возвращать просто список.

Comment: Так, по идее, падать не будет и всё заработает. Если, конечно, это всё у вас не на главном потоке исполняется. Ну и пара замечаний - AsyncTask устарел не стоит его использовать. А `LiveData` - гугловая обрезанная версия `RxJava`. Также не советую её использовать)

Comment: Насчёт `LiveData` вы ошибаетесь, это не столько про реактивные потоки, сколько про lifecycle aware. Это не замена Rx, дополнительный слой для связывания с UI

Comment: Вы меня подтолкнули погуглить насчет лайвдаты, и кажется я понял в чем ошибка - я обращаюсь к асинхронной лайвдате напрямую, и соответственно в случае если она не успела прогрузиться  - получаю нпе. Думаю весь фикс будет заключаться в том, чтоб просто подождать пока она загрузиться и все.

Comment: @LDD, вот именно. Надо подписаться и ждать.